# Pandas: Create dataframe column based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have 2 dataframes like these two:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('AABAC')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABCDEF'), 'Value':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

  Type
0    A
1    A
2    B
3    A
4    C

  Type  Value
0    A      1
1    B      2
2    C      3
3    D      4
4    E      5
5    F      6
```

I would like to add a column in df1 based on the values in df2. df2 only contains unique values, whereas df1 has multiple entries of each value.
So the resulting df1 should look like this:

```
  Type Value
0    A     1
1    A     1
2    B     2
3    A     1
4    C     3
```

My actual dataframe df1 is quite long, so I need something that is efficient (I tried it in a loop but this takes forever).

Comment: by 'the values' do you just mean the column 'Value' in df2?

Comment: There are lots of similar questions and approaches to this, have you considered `merge` for instance?

Comment: Yes, exactly, based on the column 'Value'

Comment: pd.merge will probably do it for you then.

Comment: @EdChum In the actual dataframe df2 I have more than one column, but I need only the information from 1 of those. Furthermore, when using merge, the resulting dataframe is sorted by 'Type' which I don't want: `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Type")` will sort df3.Type = A A A B C and not keep the initial order of df1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create `dict` from your `df2` with `to_dict` method and then `map` result to `Type` column for `df1`:

```
replace_dict = dict(df2.to_dict('split')['data'])

In [50]: replace_dict
Out[50]: {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6}

df1['Value'] = df1['Type'].map(replace_dict)

In [52]: df1
Out[52]:
  Type  Value
0    A      1
1    A      1
2    B      2
3    A      1
4    C      3
```

Comment: you could have set the index to 'Type' on `df2` so `df1['Value'] = df1['Type'].map(df2.set_index('Type')['Value'])` would've worked also

Comment: @EdChum this works with the above example, but not with my full dataset `pandas.core.index.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: It helps us if you post a representative example to stop wasting our time trying to help you, if you post a simplistic example you get a simplistic answer. Post either a representative example or your real data

Comment: @anton this doesn't work with my full dataset, as df2 has several columns which are however not used (I probably should have mentioned this in the first place, sorry!)

Comment: @EdChum My apologies if you feel that you are wasting your time. The real data is confidential, hence the simplified example. I'll try to find a better example

Comment: @petetheat so provide the most appropriate example for your dataframe, because for what you provide that method works fine.

Comment: @EdChum I found the problem: in my df2 I had duplicate entries I wasn't supposed to have. When I remove them, your solution works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @EdChum: You might want to add this as additional answer (I upvoted this one but actually use your solution as it avoids creating the dictionary).

Comment: @Cleb have posted my answer now

Answer (score 4):

As requested I am posting a solution that uses `map` without the need to create a temporary dict:

```
In[3]:
df1['Value'] = df1['Type'].map(df2.set_index('Type')['Value'])
df1

Out[3]: 
  Type  Value
0    A      1
1    A      1
2    B      2
3    A      1
4    C      3
```

This relies on a couple things, that the key values that are being looked up exist otherwise we get a `KeyError` and that we don't have duplicate entries in `df2` otherwise setting the index raises `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: It may help that one can always remove duplicate entries on `df2`. For example, one can use: `df2.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @JairoAlves the OP has no duplicates in `df2`, if it did you wouldn't be able to set the index to the `Type` column

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by using the label based indexer `loc`. First use the `Type` column as the index using `.set_index`, then access using the `df1` column, and reset the index to the original with `.reset_index`:

```
df2.set_index('Type').loc[df1['Type'],:].reset_index()
```

Either use this as your new `df1` or extract the `Value` column:

```
df1['Value'] = df2.set_index('Type').loc[df1['Type'],:].reset_index()['Value']
```